# Widget disappears in release.apk Flutter

Tags: android, flutter, widget

The problem is that the screen works properly in debug mode but a specific widget disappears in app-release.apk

```
Stack(
        children: [
          Container(                     <---- This widget disappears
            height: kSize.height * 0.3,
            width: kSize.width,
            child: Image(
              image: NetworkImage(
                data['cover'] != null
                    ? '$baseUrl/${data['cover']!}'
                    : 'https://icon-library.com/images/no-photo-available-icon/no-photo-available-icon-4.jpg',
              ),
            ),
          ),
          25.0.height,
          <other widget>
]),
```

I tried flutter clean and flutter pub get. It works fine for the first time but when we open app the second time the problem appears again.

Comment: What is `kSize`? Could that have anything to do with the disappearance?